# About "mirroing" a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

i would like to know how i can mirror a graph in order to, for example, transform an X axis (-200 -100 0 100 200) into (200 100 0 100 200).

I tried to do it in this script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T=1400
Q=1000
R=1000
h0=50

r=np.linspace(-R, R, 500)
s=Q*np.log(R/abs(r))/(2*np.pi*T)
npiez=h0-s
fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r,npiez)
```

And all i got was this graph:[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OElSW.png)

My objective was something like this one: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOTHc.png

Comment: X axis `(200 100 0 100 200)` makes no sense. You cannot have duplicate X values in your function, as they would render the same Y coordinate

Comment: I agree with you, in a logical way you have all reason, but i was wondering if there's a figurative method to turn the negative values into positive that dont necessarily needs to follow the math rules. I just posted a photo of a graph that was in my mind

Comment: Your usage of `abs()` seems correct... If you want to modify the **displayed** values on the X-axis, them that is a separate problem. However, anyone reading that plot may be confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify, do you only want the graph to display the positive values on the right? What does your starting plot look like and what do you want it to end as?

edit: I got it to work by modifying the xtick values with abs function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
T = 1400
Q = 1000
R = 1000
h0 = 50

r = np.linspace(-R, R, 500)
s = Q * np.log(R / np.abs(r)) / (2 * np.pi * T)
npiez = h0 - s
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(r, npiez)
ax.set_xticklabels([abs(int(x)) for x in ax.get_xticks()])

plt.show()
```

Comment: Yes sir, i want only positive values,

Comment: I got your code to work by modifying the xtick values with the abs function.. does this work for you?

Comment: Thank you so much sir, thats exactly what i wanted, you helped a lot :).